# Problems with Raspberry Pi SD card

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi

Today I booted up my Raspberry Pi just to find this error during boot:

```
[....] Checking root file system...Segmentation fault
failed (code 139)
[....] An automatic file system check (fsck) of the root file system failed. A manual fsck must be performed, then the system restarted. The fsck should be performed in maintenance mode with the root filesystem mounted in read-only.
[warn] The root filesystem is currently mounted in read-only mode. A maintenance shell will now be started. After performing system maintenance, press CONTROL-D to terminate the maintenance shell and restart the system.
Give root password for maintenance:
```

So I login as root and run:

```
root@pi# fsck
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
fsck: Warning... fsck.ext for device /dev/mmcblk0p2 exited with signal 4.
```

Next I have connected the SD card to a working system, and run:

```
root# fdisk -l
Device     Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1         8192   122879   114688   56M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdb2       122880 30679039 30556160 14.6G 83 Linux

root# fsck -a /dev/sdb2
fsck from util-linux 2.25.2
/dev/sdb2: clean, 148547/941616 files, 1144972/3819520 blocks
```

So I put the card back into my RPI but I get the same error.

How do I fix that card?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure there is not something wrong with RPI the card reader?
In that case, you should try booting from another card/ another device.

Comment: RPI is fine. Tested it with another card.

Comment: You may try to fix it on a regular PC, with more recent Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by running:

```
root# fsck /dev/sdb2 -a -f
fsck from util-linux 2.25.2
/dev/sdb2: Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.

/dev/sdb2: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
        (i.e., without -a or -p options)
root# fsck /dev/sdb2 -f
fsck from util-linux 2.25.2
e2fsck 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 449 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 464 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 880 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 3478 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.

[......]

root# fsck /dev/sdb2 -f
fsck from util-linux 2.25.2
e2fsck 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/sdb2: 148489/941616 files (0.4% non-contiguous), 1139108/3819520 blocks
```